# Attack on RSA when I know $e$, ciphertexts $c_1, c_2$ of the same message $m$ with 2 coprime modules?

Tags: rsa, attack

I know that the same message $m$ was sent to two people resulting in ciphertexts $c_1, c_2$. The public keys are $n_1$ and $n_2$, $gcd(n_1, n_2) = 1$. And $e=3$ in both cases. How can I retrieve the original message without brute-forcing it?

I.e. the exponent $e$ is the same in both public keys, but the modulus $n$ is different: $n_1, n_2$.

Comment: My question is different: e is the same, n is different

Comment: CRT based attack requires 3 ciphertexts for $e=3$ See the comment at [Low Public Exponent Attack for RSA](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6713/low-public-exponent-attack-for-rsa)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem seems like a variant of [Håstad's broadcast attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith%27s_attack#H%C3%A5stad's_broadcast_attack), except that is usually stated with $e$ ciphertexts, when here there is $2<e$ ciphertexts.

We know $m^e$ modulo $n_1$ and modulo $n_2$ (that's the givens $c_1$ and $c_2$), thus we can compute $m^e\bmod(n_1\,n_2)=y$ using the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem), per $y\gets(n_2^{-1}(c_1-c_2)\bmod n_1)\,n_2+c_2$

If we are lucky enough that $m<\left\lfloor\sqrt[e]{n_1\,n_2}\right\rfloor$ (roughly, $m$ of bit size less than $1/e$ of the sum of the bit sizes of the moduli), then $y$ will be exactly the $e^\text{th}$ power of some integer $x$, we can get that $x$, and it will be $m$.

If not, we can try, for incremental $i$, if any of the $y_i=i\,c_1\,c_2+y$ is exactly an $e^\text{th}$ power; that slightly extends the attack.

Note: none of this is RSA as correctly practiced. What's raised to the power $e$ modulo $n$ should not be the message, but a randomly padded message (per e.g. [RSAES-OAEP](https://www.emc.com/collateral/white-papers/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp.pdf#page=16)) computed separately for each ciphertext sent, and almost as wide as the public modulus.

Comment: in this question's answer [Deciphering the RSA encrypted message from three different public keys](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/52504/deciphering-the-rsa-encrypted-message-from-three-different-public-keys/52519#52519) says that you need $e$ ciphertext.

Comment: @kelalaka: we need $e=3$ ciphertext for the attack to succeed for any $m$, and that's how the standard Håstad's broadcast attack is usually stated. This is a variant, and it will succeed only if $m$ is small enough.

Comment: I'm fine with your solution. if $e=5$ then 5 $c$'s?

Comment: @kelalaka: yes the standard Håstad's broadcast attack works for 5 $c_i$ when $e=5$, whatever $m$. It could work for less $c_i$ for small enough $m$, namely for $m<\left\lfloor\sqrt[e]{\displaystyle\prod n_i}\right\rfloor$ (or slightly above that thresold with some extra guesswork)